# Changing content of a button in WPF dynamically to selected file name

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm

I am trying to change the content name of a button dynamically in c# WPF when a file is selected after clicking the button. I am using MVVM in this method. I have tried to insert a click event but it won't work in this method because the click event will always happen first before the command event. I have researched in StackExchange for solutions but what I saw are generally trigger events and to create a command which calls multiple commands. I could use some pointers on the methodology that is best suited to change the content name of a button.

> I have the following hierarchy in MVVM (Modifications should still follow this hierarchy)

In my XAML I have created a button with `Content="Import File"` I would like to dynamically change this when a file is selected. I used the command method here and delegate method in my view method to call my methods.

```
<Button  x:Name="SelectFile" Margin="0 0 0 0" Content="Import File"  Command="{Binding ImportExcelBtn, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In the view model, I am using the delegate command method as so. I have gotten the file name as `string FileName` but I can't seem to find a way to bind the method and change the content name of the button.

```
public DelegateCommand ImportExcelBtn
    {
        get { return _importExcelBtn; }
        set
        {
            _importExcelBtn = value;
            SetPropertyChanged("ImportExcelBtn");
        }
    }

public ViewModel()
    {
        modelView = new ModelView();
        ImportExcelBtn = new DelegateCommand(ImportExcelFileAction);//From model
    }
private void ImportExcelFileAction()
        {
            excelFile = ImportFile();//get excel file from method
            string name = excelFile .ToString();
            int position = name.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1;
            string FileName = name.Substring(position, name.Length - position);
        }
```

In my model, I have a method to select the file. (My script is running successfully here)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the `Content` to a property in ViewModel and change it when you get the file name. For example, in your ViewModel

```
public string ContentValue {get;set;} = "Import File";
```

And in Xaml

```
Content="{Binding ContentValue}"
```

Later, when you have the file name, you could update the `ContentValue`

```
private void ImportExcelFileAction()
{
excelFile = ImportFile();//get excel file from method
string name = excelFile .ToString();
int position = name.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1;
string FileName = name.Substring(position, name.Length - position);
ContentValue  = FileName;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ContentValue)); //Call Notify Property Changed
}
```

Comment: You're my savior. Thank you for expanding my knowledge about binding values from the view model to the XAML. I have one thing to add, in your comment, you've stated to use "NotifyPropertyChange" (I've edited and waiting for a peer review) but that causes an error in my script. I had to use "OnPropertyChange" instead. God bless!